# Connect Joomla with Linkedin

Tags: joomla, linkedin-api

I am looking for a way to connect a form in Joomla with LinkedIn.

When a user clicks on a link in LinkedIn, the user gets redirected to my landing page. On my landing page, there is a form with name, lastname, email. I would like this information to be filled out with the information from LinkedIn.

Does anybody knows if that is possible without a paid plugin for Joomla?

Comment: specificity + grammar

Comment: ? That was a weird comment

Comment: I forgot the editor actually posts up the comment here, @M375. I shall be more verbose next time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technically, this cannot be done because if it can be done then this means that LinkedIn has a huge security flaw (e.g. any website you click on its link from LinkedIn can grab your data).

If you want to have access to the LinkedIn data, then you must use the LinkedIn API and users must authorize your website (application) to retrieve their data.